# Preserve 'this' with jQuery.bind?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

I want to bind an event to a **jQuery** element so it calls a function in my class, but when the function gets called, `this` variable no longer points to the class, instead pointing to the sender element.

```
this.remove = function() {
    alert(this); 
    /* Shows [object HTMLImageElement] instead of the desired class */
    this.dv.remove(); /* error */
}

$(this.buttons['cancel']).bind("click", this.remove);
```

**How can I get around that?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$(this.buttons['cancel']).bind("click", $.proxy(this.remove, this));`

Where the second argument is the context that you want the method to execute in.

Answer (score 4):

Just put the correct `this` in a closure:

```
var that = this;

this.remove = function() {
    alert(that); 
    that.dv.remove();
}

$(this.buttons['cancel']).bind("click", this.remove);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery `proxy` to preserve the context.

```
this.remove = function() {
    alert(this); 
    /* Shows [object HTMLImageElement] instead of the desired class */
    this.dv.remove(); /* error */
}

//Now in the click handler this will point to the context which we pass in $.proxy
$(this.buttons['cancel']).bind("click", $.proxy(this.remove, this));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call it inside a function, just using `this.remove` won't have the desired effect. And, you have to capture `this` in a different variable, because it will change inside the function:

```
var self = this;
$(this.buttons['cancel']).bind("click", function () { self.remove(); });
```